# Why is CIFS mounting with sticky bit

Tags: mount, permissions, samba, fstab, cifs

I have a CIFS mount that's being mounted in `fstab` and looks like this:

```
//192.168.1.97/media /home/pi/sambashare cifs credentials=/.credentials/.smbcredentials,rw,iocharset=utf8,nounix,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

It works fine, with the exception that all of the folder permissions have the sticky bit on. I run a few programs as different users, so need to be able to have `rw` access to all the folders as different users, but the sticky bit is preventing me from making changes as the other users.

Have tried mounting with GID and UID also, but:

1. User is always `libuuid` and group is always `1002` regardless of what GID and UID says
2. I have different users that need access.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: are you sure it is an "s" (=sticky bit) and not an "S" (sgid bit=mandatory locking)? ;-)